# Thread call from Abstract Class for child classes?

Tags: java, multithreading

Hi so I have repetitive Code and want to get rid of it.
I want to get rid of the scheduler call (scheduler.schedule(this::transition, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);) because its copy paste code. But I dont know how to put it in an Abstract Class so that it will be executed properly in every Stage. The "this::transition" makes it impossible for me.

```
public class Stage1 {
 private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler  = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

public void transition() {
...
scheduler.schedule(this::transition, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
}

public class Stage2 {
 private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler  = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

public void transition() {
...
scheduler.schedule(this::transition, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
}

public class Stage3 {
 private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler  = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

public void transition() {
...
scheduler.schedule(this::transition, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
}
```

Comment: Create an abstract method that `transition` calls?

Comment: how should that looks like in code?

Comment: `abstract class Stage { void transition() { /* call abstract method ... reschedule */ } abstract void abstractMethod(); }`

Comment: But that's assuming I understand what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Extract the scheduling business logic to some outer class and inject this into your `Stage` classes - this scheduler should provide some `schedule` method with at least one parameter - the reference to the method that should be scheduled

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class StageN {

   private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler  = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

   int n;
   Runnable todo;
    
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      //with lambda
      new StageN(1, () -> { 
         // DO SOMETHING 
      }).transition();

    //without lambda
     new StageN(2,new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
         // DO SOMETHING 
            }
      }).transition();
    }

    public StageN(int n, Runnable todo) {
        this.n = n;
        this.todo = todo;
    }

    public void transition() {
        todo.run();
        scheduler.schedule(this::transition, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```